# Transparent Background But Visible Graphics

Tags: vb.net, winforms, transparency

I have a bit of a peculiar problem I can't get through. I'm trying to make an overlay that is completely transparent, however, I must be able to click through it to an underlying form. These overlaying forms are not childed to anything. Each overlay form contains one panel. However, I can't seem to get the transparency I need without completely making the entire form invisible. What can I do?

Here is the code for my form.

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class frmOverlay

    Public ChartProperty As strChartProperty
    Private InitialStyle As Integer
    Dim PercentVisible As Decimal

    Public Sub New(ByRef chartProperties As strChartProperty)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        ChartProperty = chartProperties
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
        BackColor = Color.Transparent
        ForeColor = Color.Transparent
        Opacity = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitialStyle = GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20)
        PercentVisible = 0.5
        SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20, InitialStyle Or &H80000 Or &H20)
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.Handle, 0, 255 * PercentVisible, &H2)
        Me.TopMost = True

        Dim panel As New OverlayPanel
        Controls.Add(panel)
    End Sub

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong")> Public Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong")> Public Shared Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetLayeredWindowAttributes")> Public Shared Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal crKey As Integer, ByVal alpha As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Sub frmOverlay_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ResizeEnd
        ResumeLayout()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmOverlay_ResizeBegin(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ResizeBegin
        SuspendLayout()
    End Sub

    Public Class OverlayPanel
        Inherits Panel

        Public Event Event_RedrawRequest(ByRef e As PaintEventArgs)

        Public Sub New()
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.UserPaint Or ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
            UpdateStyles()
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
            Dim ChartProperty As strChartProperty = DirectCast(Me.Parent, frmOverlay).ChartProperty
            With e.Graphics
                .Clear(Me.Parent.BackColor)
                .SmoothingMode = IIf(ChartProperty.MaxDrawSpeed, Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighSpeed, Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias)
                .TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias '.ClearTypeGridFit
                .CompositingQuality = IIf(ChartProperty.MaxDrawSpeed, Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed, Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality)
            End With

            MyBase.OnPaint(e)
            RaiseEvent Event_RedrawRequest(e)
            Debug.Print("Overlay had to paint")
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: Windows forms transparency "cheats" at this. It takes a picture of what's behind you on the desktop uses that as the background. So if you have stuff moving behind your app, you can weird results. If you need real transparency, you need WPF.

Comment: Oh boy :( okay I was hoping that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: In fairness, I've used Windows Forms transparency quite a bit, and people hardly ever notice the weakness.

Comment: The issue is my desktop background happens to be black and since it is an overlay over a white form, the black is very noticeable.

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do. You want a completely transparent click through form or not? what the purpose of the panel? does the form has borders? the size of the form is the same as the screen?

Comment: No it should act as a completely transparent template that I can draw graphics on top of but has 0 background color.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do it is by using `UpdateLayeredWindow` [UpdateLayeredWindow function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow). This function sets a 32 bit bitmap to your window form. It can be used to child windows too after windows 8:

> Windows 8:  The WS_EX_LAYERED style is supported for top-level windows and child windows. Previous Windows versions support WS_EX_LAYERED only for top-level windows.

Using this function means that you can have a complete transparent window **and** draw graphics **but** none of the paint that any window or you do can be visible! You have to do all the drawings to the 32bit bitmap and call `UpdateLayeredWindow` to see the results. If you have multiple child windows you do get all the events but only if the mouse is on top of a non complete transparent pixel. A little trick is to set the `alpha` to the lowest `1` so you have transparency but also get all the events from your windows.  Because you want a click trough form it doesn't matter. Now the code:

Create a class to hold all your APIs

```
Public Class APIHelp

    Public Const WS_EX_LAYERED As Int32 = &H80000
    Public Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Int32 = &H20
    Public Const ULW_ALPHA As Int32 = 2
    Public Const AC_SRC_OVER As Byte = 0
    Public Const AC_SRC_ALPHA As Byte = 1

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure Point
        Public x As Int32
        Public y As Int32

        Public Sub New(ByVal x As Int32, ByVal y As Int32)
            Me.x = x
            Me.y = y
        End Sub
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure Size
        Public cx As Int32
        Public cy As Int32

        Public Sub New(ByVal cx As Int32, ByVal cy As Int32)
            Me.cx = cx
            Me.cy = cy
        End Sub
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
    Private Structure ARGB
        Public Blue As Byte
        Public Green As Byte
        Public Red As Byte
        Public Alpha As Byte
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
    Public Structure BLENDFUNCTION
        Public BlendOp As Byte
        Public BlendFlags As Byte
        Public SourceConstantAlpha As Byte
        Public AlphaFormat As Byte
    End Structure

    Public Declare Auto Function UpdateLayeredWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hdcDst As IntPtr, ByRef pptDst As Point, ByRef psize As Size, ByVal hdcSrc As IntPtr, ByRef pprSrc As Point,
                      ByVal crKey As Int32, ByRef pblend As BLENDFUNCTION, ByVal dwFlags As Int32) As Bool

    Public Declare Auto Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hDC As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    Public Declare Auto Function GetDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    <DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Public Shared Function ReleaseDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hDC As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    Public Declare Auto Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr) As Bool

    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Public Shared Function SelectObject(ByVal hDC As IntPtr, ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    Public Declare Auto Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Bool

    Public Declare Auto Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Double

    <DllImport("User32", SetLastError:=True)> Friend Shared Function ReleaseCapture() As Boolean
    End Function

End Class
```

Call this function to see your graphics:

```
Public Sub UpdateLayeredBitmap(ByVal bitmap As Bitmap)
    'Does this bitmap contain an alpha channel?
    If bitmap.PixelFormat <> PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb Then
        Throw New ApplicationException("The bitmap must be 32bpp with alpha-channel.")
    End If

    'Get device contexts
    Dim screenDc As IntPtr = APIHelp.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)
    Dim memDc As IntPtr = APIHelp.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDc)
    Dim hBitmap As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim hOldBitmap As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    Try
        ' Get handle to the new bitmap and select it into the current device context
        hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0))
        hOldBitmap = APIHelp.SelectObject(memDc, hBitmap)

        Dim blend As APIHelp.BLENDFUNCTION = New APIHelp.BLENDFUNCTION()

        ' Only works with a 32bpp bitmap
        blend.BlendOp = APIHelp.AC_SRC_OVER
        ' Always 0
        blend.BlendFlags = 0
        ' Set to 255 for per-pixel alpha values
        blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255
        ' Only works when the bitmap contains an alpha channel
        blend.AlphaFormat = APIHelp.AC_SRC_ALPHA

        Dim sourceLocation As New APIHelp.Point(0, 0)
        Dim newLocation As New APIHelp.Point(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y)
        Dim newSize As New APIHelp.Size(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height)

        'Update the window
        APIHelp.UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, newLocation, newSize, memDc, sourceLocation,
         0, Blend, APIHelp.ULW_ALPHA)
    Finally
        ' Release device context
        'APIHelp.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, screenDc)
        If hBitmap <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            APIHelp.SelectObject(memDc, hOldBitmap)
            ' Remove bitmap resources
            APIHelp.DeleteObject(hBitmap)
        End If
        APIHelp.DeleteDC(memDc)
        APIHelp.DeleteDC(screenDc)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Set the ex styles to your form:

```
Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        'Add the layered extended style (WS_EX_LAYERED) to this window
        Dim createParam As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        createParam.ExStyle = createParam.ExStyle Or APIHelp.WS_EX_LAYERED Or APIHelp.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        Return createParam
    End Get
End Property
```

An example how you do it, this is the only way you can draw graphics:

```
Private backBitmapEmpty As Bitmap 'it is better to keep it private so to use it over and over

'create a 32 bit bitmap
backBitmapEmpty = New Bitmap(Me.Size.Width, Me.Size.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(backBitmapEmpty)

With g
    .SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    .TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias '.ClearTypeGridFit
    .CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
End With

'make bitmap completely transparent
g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0))

g.DrawString("Some text", Me.Font, Brushes.Green, New PointF(150.0F, 150.0F))

g.Dispose()

'inform system that bitmap has changed
UpdateLayeredBitmap(backBitmapEmpty)
```